# Java Generics : Object Mapper Converting JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, generics, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I would like to deserialize a json string to a java object. I wanted to write a generic method.

```
public class ObjectSerializer<T> {

    T t;
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


  /*  public Person deSerial(String json) throws Exception {
        TypeReference<Person> typeRef = new TypeReference<Person>() {};

        return mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    } */

    public T deSerialize(String jsonInput) throws Exception {
        TypeReference<T> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<T>() {};

       return mapper.readValue(jsonInput, typeRef);
    }
}
```

When I call `deSerialize(validPersonJsonString) [validPersonJsonString : valid person JSON String]`, it is not working, it it throwing me the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.Person.
```

Whereas, when in call the commented `deSerial` method, it works fine. Please explain the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point for using a generic here. Just pass the desired class to `deSerialize`, so calling it like `deSerialize(json, Person.class);`. Much easier, less boilerplate.

Comment: HI @Tom, Tomorrow I want to use with Employee.class how would I use it? I don't want to write another method for Employee.class

Comment: @Raghu use Class<T>? exactly the same way ObjectMapper already does to allow you to make JSONs into objects.

Comment: use deSerialize(json,class<T> clazz) for generic

Comment: @SHAHAKASH Your comment is wrong. You're mixing a method definition and the method call.

Comment: Still not clear with how to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson doesn't support `TypeReference` with generic type parameters because of type erasure. [Here's](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1490) the bug about it.

As far as your use case is concerned, you don't need to use `ObjectSerializer` class at all. You can directly expose `ObjectMapper` object to your service layer and perform the deserialization.

If you want to shield the `json` serializing mechanism from your service layer then you can wrap `ObjectMapper` implementation into another class (like you have done in your code) but then, accept the class type as a method argument rather than a generic type.

Comment: Person person = mapper.readValue(inputJson,Person.class); Thanks. Accepted the answer.